# Saving a laptop to laptop ethernet (crossover) connection's details

Tags: networking, ethernet, lan, crossover

I am trying to connect a Windows 7 and A Windows 10 laptop via a crossover ethernet cable. But the connection settings reset every time I disconnect them and I have to re-enter all the details.

Everything else works just fine and I can share files.
But I need some settings, such as IP assignment to not change every time I disconnect and reconnect these laptops.

Also, the network just says "Unidentified network".

How do I keep the configuration saved and change the name of the network?

Comment: Which settings reset, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Set your network connections to be Static IP.

Map from Windows 10 to Windows 7 (not the other way around). Set the sharing connection to be persistent.  That might work.

In Windows 10 File Explorer, right click on Network, Map Network Drive.  Enter the connection parameters and click on Remember this Connection.

See the 2 screen shots for this.

[image: Map Network Drive]

and

[image: Persistent Connections]

Crossover connections are normally only temporary so the above settings most likely will not work when connected by crossover, and you will have to enter settings each time. In a regular connection, I use the above settings all the time.

On the rare occasion when I did use crossover cables, I used the NET USE T: \machine\folder to share files. That works when Map Network Drive does not.

Comment: You are right, there doesn't seem to be a way to do it. The "Enter the connection parameters" option doesn't show up when I right click network.

Comment: Right clicking on Network should at least give you the screen. I added screen shots. That may depend on having a standard network connection (not sure).  But saving connections is most likely not possible for Crossover connections. I did make my answer more clear that what you want will likely not work.

Comment: I also showed the use of NET USE to map folders. I have used this many times, especially when I did use a crossover cable.

Answer (score -3):

Good evening from Australia Tanay.

The reason that your connection settings are always resetting is because of the operating systems used.

They have different LAN connection settings.

Your also using 2 different laptops with different specs (unless they are the same, with just 1 being an older model).

I advise that you contact Microsoft, and their community in regards to your issue.

Contact the community about the Windows 7 laptop, as Microsoft no longer supports Windows 7 Home, and then contact Microsoft about your Windows 10 laptop.

It'll be tedious, but, I'm sure they'll have an answer for you.

Comment: Ethernet is a standard, so is IP and DNS. Why would laptop specs matter? This is a non-answer, you just told OP to go ask somewhere else.